# sending tcp data every 10 seconds - but actually send each 20 seconds

Tags: c#

i wrote some simpler code that send byte array data to some tcp socket.
i did this before many times - but this for some reason not work as i expected.

I see on the log that my main thread that suppose to sleep until for 10 second - its actually sleep 24 seconds before sending the next package

i can't fine logical explain for this.
also try to run the main loop ( and sending ) from different thread ... same result

The code :

```
public class Program
{
    static List<byte[]> _dataToSend = new List<byte[]>();
    static TcpClient _tcpClient = new TcpClient();


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //
        //  init the TCP client => connect successful 

        //  add data to the _dataToSend 

        foreach (byte[] item in _dataToSend)
        {

            _tcpClient.Client.Send(item);

            Thread.Sleep(10000);       // 10 second
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're sleeping for 10 seconds *after* sending the item. How long does sending the item take?

Comment: Yeah. I would start looking into async here (wasting a thread to sleep 10 seconds - ouch). THen you could basically send the data, wait and then await to see how the last send was finished.

Comment: sending take 10-20 milliseconds

Comment: i don't want to use in this case the async

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the delay on `TcpClient`:

```
_tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, sending the data might take some additional time. So, what you could do is calculate the remaining time-span that you need to wait for.

Try something like this:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();

foreach (byte[] item in _dataToSend)
{
    sw.Restart();

    _tcpClient.Client.Send(item);

    int remainingMilliseconds = (int)(10000 - sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    if (remainingMilliseconds > 0) Thread.Sleep(remainingMilliseconds);
}
```

That way, if the sending takes 5 seconds, for example, you only wait for 5 additional seconds. If the sending takes more than 10 seconds, you don't wait at all.